# How to handle an API response that might be an empty object with rxjs Observables?

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3

**I can edit both the frontend and the backend**

I have a service that fetches a communique. This communique might exist (there is one communique active) or might not (there is no communique active), so the API might respond with the JSON object of the communique, or with an empty JSON object.

I am handling it this way:

```
getCommunique(): Observable<Communique | {}> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/getCommunique').map((response) => {
    if (Object.keys(response.json()).length != 0) {
      return new Communique(response.json())
    } else {
      return {}
    }
  });
}
```

This is my `Communique` class:

```
export class Comunique {
  public id: number;
  public title: string;
  public content: string;
  public date: Date;
  public url: string;
  public imageUrl: string;

  constructor(input: ComuniqueRaw) {
    this.id = input.id;
    this.title = input.title;
    this.content = input.content;
    this.date = new Date(input.date.timestamp * 1000);
    this.url = 'url' + input.slug;
    this.imageUrl = 'url' + input.image;
  }
}
```

This works... But it seems like a workaround. Shouldn't the observable only return `Communique` objects? But if there is not an active communique, how would the `Communique` object be created? I mean, I can add a field with something like `public exists: boolean;` in the `Communique` class, but that seems like a workaround too (an object that only holds a single `boolean`).

Am I handling it the right way? Or... How to handle an API response that might be an empty object with rxjs Observables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http.get() observable always returns once and only once. If the server responds with an empty object, it's not the http client's responsibility to ignore it - it's a valid http response.

I would say that your server should return a 404 if there is no communique object, and you catch that with an rxjs catchError, which would handle that case separately.

Edit:

If you would prefer to always return a 200 with either an empty response or an object, then the pattern you have implemented seems fine.

Edit2:

I've just noticed you're using the old .map() method. My catchError() answer would be for using the relatively new pipe operators.

```
getCommunique(): Observable<Communique> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/getCommunique').pipe(
    map(response => new Communique(response.json())),
    catchError(() => of(null))
  );
}
```

Comment: Typo in map. If you are using Angular 7+, then it should be mapTo()

Comment: No. mapTo ignores the input. In this case we want to map the input response to a new Communique object.